# Chrome DevTools - Refresh IndexedDB data while on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When you're paused on a breakpoint in Chrome's debugger, is there a way of refreshing the IndexedDB view? The refresh button doesn't appear disabled, but the data doesn't actually refresh until you resume the debugger. I would imagine this is because under the hood chrome freezes the main javascript thread (which devtools also uses), but IndexedDB *can be accessed from multiple threads* so is there a way to get around this?

[image: screenshot from devtools]

I'm trying to use the debugger to view the intermediate state of an object store during a function call - I could just use `console.log`s instead but that defeats the point of using a debugger in the first place

Comment: I'd consider this a bug in devtools. A workaround might be to create a dummy Worker and open a separate devtools for it via chrome://inspect

Comment: Good idea, but I can't get my db to show up at all on that inspector (ie the IndexedDB tab shows up as completely empty) - I'll file a bug report and post the link here if it goes anywhere

Comment: Sadly [the issue I posted](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/327877733) was marked as "Intended behavior / won't fix" so you can't use devtools for this